# figcaps package: How to print figure captions and then tables?

Tags: floats

I am using figcaps package, it puts at the end Tables and then Figure captions. I want to have first Figure captions and then Tables. Is there any solution?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{figcaps}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!hbt]
\caption{Figure 1. \label{Fig1}}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table 1}
   \begin{tabular}{l| l}
     1 & 2
    \end{tabular}
 \end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is there any code to work with? ;-)

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence Thank you, I will add the code.

Comment: `figcaps` is a very old package, actually

Comment: Is there a newer alternative?

Comment: There is \captionof from the caption package.

Answer (score 1):

The `figcaps` package uses

```
\AtEndDocument{\iffigcaps\@tablepage\@figurecaps\@figurepage\fi}
```

to typeset tables first and then the figure captions. This use of `\AtEndDocument` unfortunately makes that the solution cannot be given from your `.tex` file. However, there's a solution. Save a copy of `figcaps.sty` as `myfigcaps.sty` in the same directory where your `.tex` is. Open `myfigcaps.sty` and change the line

```
\AtEndDocument{\iffigcaps\@tablepage\@figurecaps\@figurepage\fi}
```

to

```
\AtEndDocument{\iffigcaps\@figurecaps\@figurepage\@tablepage\fi}
```

save the changes and load `myfigcaps` in your document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{myfigcaps}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure 1. \label{Fig1}}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table 1}
   \begin{tabular}{l| l}
     1 & 2
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This now produces

[image]

Perhaps you could consider switching to the more modern [`endfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) package which allows more control over how the delayed elements are typeset.